# Spaces in Markdown code block not rendering

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

In my Jupyter notebook I have the following Markdown code block:

`````
    ````python
                                [[0 1 0 0 0 0]
   [0 1 1 0 1 1]       -         [0 0 1 0 0 0]
                                 [0 0 0 0 1 0]
                                 [0 0 0 0 0 1]]
    ````
`````

which is rather unexpectedly rendering as[image: Rendering on Nbviewer] on my local machine as well as on Nbviewer. In other words the whitespace in front of the first vector `[[0 1 0 0 0 0]` seems to be getting ignored. I have used single spaces to create this whitespace, not tabs.

Any idea on how to resolve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: 1) It is not valid Python code so it may be rendered in any way whatsoever; use latex equation for vectors and matrices instead 2) You have extra indent, not sure if on purpose. 3) your second line containing a vector is missing one space indentation on the left; after adding the missing space and removing the unneeded indentation level it works both in Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab

Comment: Thanks @krassowski, adding one space on the left worked.